# Internally handling odd number of lines in GNU sed - is my solution exploiting a bug?

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I have a series of tokens like

```
Filename
URL
Filename
URL
...
```

and I wanted to group them onto the same line, then reverse the token order, so I did

```
$ echo -e 'Filename\nURL\nFilename\nURL' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
URL Filename
URL Filename
```

which I have no problems with.

However, the `N` operator in `sed` is quite fragile, so I wanted to ensure that wonky input like...

```
$ echo -e 'Filename\nURL\nFilename' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
URL Filename
Filename
```

...doesn't ruin everything. But I wanted to keep it to a oneliner, and try and use `sed` builtins if I can.

I accidentally discovered:

```
$ echo -e 'hi\nabc\ndef\nghi' | sed '$q1;N;s/\n/ | /' && echo -n even || echo -n odd; echo ' number of input lines'
hi | abc
def | ghi
even number of input lines

$ echo -e 'hi\nabc\ndef' | sed '$q1;N;s/\n/ | /' && echo -n even || echo -n odd; echo ' number of input lines'
hi | abc
def
odd number of input lines
```

It seems that the `$` operator does not report EOF if an `N` munges the line immediately beforehand.

I'm guessing this a bug and that I shouldn't depend on it...?

Comment: `$` matches the last line in the file. If you do something that prevents sed from operating on the last line in the file normally then it shouldn't match anything I think. I believe that's intended behavior. But I don't have any proof and don't use sed much so I don't think I can officially "answer" this.

Comment: Interesting... I was going in that direction too, but I thought `$` should *always* match the last line regardless of the situation. It's interesting how much of `sed`'s internal state can be manipulated!

Comment: That's the thing it is the address of the last line but you just swallowed the last line and so that address never matches. sed would need to go back and re-evaluate the entire command when you used `N` to do that if it wanted to trigger `$` on the new last line (not to mention that doing that might potentially invalidate the part of the command that caused `N` to happen to begin with).

Comment: Oh wow. You're right, I never really got that far in my understanding of the parsing. I think you've nailed it, and unless you want to wait a bit for others to chime in, I wouldn't mind accepting this as an answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` commands are matched in order. That's the key here.

Assume an input file like this:

```
URL 1
Filename 1
URL 2
Filename 2
```

What happens when `sed` processes the file is that `sed` reads the first line, matches it against `$` (which fails) then runs the `N` and `s` commands.

It then reads the "next" line (which is now line three, the `URL 2` line) matches that against `$` (which fails) and then runs the `N` and `s` commands. At which point `sed` then tries to read the next line to prep for the next run through the input only there isn't any more input and so it exits.

Now assume an input file of

```
URL 1
Filename 1
Filename 2
```

`sed` starts by reading the first line, matching it against `$` (which fails) and then performs the `N` and `s` commands. It then reads the "next" line (again line three, this time the `Filename 2` line) and matches that against `$` (which *succeeds*) and then quits.

If you had a `$` addressed command *after* the `N` command that would trigger on a file with an even number of lines (as `sed` would now be on the last line when that command is running).

Example:

```
$ printf %s\\n "U 1" "F 1" "U 2" "F 2" | sed '$q1;N;s/\n/ | /;$s/$/ - last line/' && echo even || echo odd
U 1 | F 1
U 2 | F 2 - last line
even
$ printf %s\\n "U 1" "F 1" "F 2" | sed '$q1;N;s/\n/ | /;$s/$/ - last line/' && echo even || echo odd
U 1 | F 1
F 2
odd
```

Comment: You can switch `sed '$q1;N;s/\n/ | /'` to `sed 'N;$q1;s/\n/ | /'` to better prove your point i think.When sed reaches the end of the file, that's it, it doesn't reprocess the line, so if the command `N` get to the last line then if `$` is after it then it will be processed, but if it is before then the command is never run.

Comment: @User112638726 That script is the OPs original. I didn't want to modify it. I could have used that for part of the in-order point though.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, and in such ambiguous form too. :D